# Option to join objects in list with list from other db

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, razor, entity-framework-core

I have 2 databases and folowing models

For db 1:

```
Public class StorageItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

for db 2:

```
public class Storage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    publict string name {get; set;}
    public int StorageItemId{ get; set; } 
}
```

I have the methods

```
var storageitemList = context.StorageItem.ToList();
```

and

```
var storageList = context.Storage.ToList();
```

I would like to add to the corresponding name from the storageitemList to the StorageList.
StorageList will result in something like this and each storagelist object is still accessible.

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 2 | test2 |

| id | name | storageitemId | StorageItemName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test12 | 1 | test |
| 2 | test4 | 2 | test2 |

Currently the string name is stored in the database but this will be changed to the Id.
But the name needs still be showed in the Razor/blazor frontend page like now.
Do i need to make a new Class to combine them or a property bag?
What is the best solution to achieve this?

I started looking at PropertyBag to achieve something like:
Status["name"]=storageitemlist.where(si=> si.id == storage.id);
but cant find the propertybag solution for models.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      var query = (from storage in storageList
                         join storageitem in storageitemList on storage.StorageItemId equals storageitem.Id
                         select (storage: storage, storageitem: storageitem)).ToList();
```

And `List<(Storage storage, StorageItem storageitem)>` has model in your view

You can also create a new dto class for the model

it is better to avoid using the viewbags

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify what you need exactly ...
What I did understand from the post is you need something like Zip operation in linq

*from (C# in nutshell)*

**The Zip Operator**

`IEnumerable<TFirst>, IEnumerable<TSecond>→IEnumerable<TResult>`

The Zip operator was added in Framework 4.0.
It enumerates two sequences in step (like a zipper), returning a sequence based on applying a function over each element pair.

```
For instance, the following:
int[] numbers = { 3, 5, 7 };
string[] words = { "three", "five", "seven", "ignored" };
IEnumerable<string> zip = numbers.Zip (words, (n, w) => n + "=" + w);
```

produces a sequence with the following elements:

```
3=three
5=five
7=seven
```

Extra elements in either input sequence are ignored. Zip is not supported by EF
Core.

Comment: I think something like that. I have 2 lists of objects 1: StatusItem 2: status. Both have a status ID but only statusItem has the string. Statusitem is stored in 1 db and status in the second db. I want to show the correspending string from the id from status in the user interface.

Comment: I started looking at PropertyBag to achieve something like: Status["name"]=storageitemlist.where(si=> si.id == storage.id); but cant find the propertybag solution for models.